# Decrease input number in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, input

I just started learning javascript. I develop an input box that user enters a number in. so program decrease number to zero.
my problem is here; I enter a number and show same it in output, but show a decreasing number.
my JS code :

```js
function test() {
  var MyInput = parseInt(document.getElementById('HoursOfWork').value);
  var Exp_MyInput = document.getElementById('output01').innerHTML = "Number: " + MyInput;
  for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
    document.getElementById('output01').innerHTML = MyInput;
  }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="StyleSheet.css" />
  <script src="Script.js"></script>


  <title>EyeProctect Project</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Eye Protect</h1>
  <h4>Keep Your Eyes safe</h4>
  <input type="text" id="HoursOfWork" placeholder="Enter your hours of work ...." />
  <button class="start" onclick=test()>Let's Go!</button>
  <p id="output01"></p>

</body>

</html>
```

What am I do?

Comment: You are just setting the innerHTML of that `<p>` to `MyInput` 3 times. What are you trying to accomplish with this code?

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: Is that what you want ? https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/jnwrc5ay/1116/

Comment: Your declaration line of MyInput gets the value abd converts it to an integer (good catch) but I don't see anywhere that you're actually subtracting a number. Plus for loops are crazy fast, look at setInterval or setTimeout to create a good countdown, that won't resolve in milliseconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you meant counting down from number provided in input field down to zero using for loop then you can work with this approach:

```js
function test() {
  var MyInput = parseInt(document.getElementById('HoursOfWork').value);
  var output = document.getElementById('output01');
  output.innerHTML = '';

  for (var i = MyInput; i > 0; i--) {
    output.innerHTML += "Number: " + i + "<br>";
  }     
}
```